# Complex polynomial that has no roots in the closed unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $c_0 > c_1 >... > c_n > 0$. Show that the polynomial $p(z) = c_0 + c_1z+...+c_nz^n$ has no zeros in the closed unit disc. My proof is not self-contained at all, and I've no idea how to approach the problem.

Comment: Here is an idea: Try to solve for zero in the case $n=1$ and use $c_0 > c_1$. Then use this for induction to get a result for arbitrary $n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $$(1-z) p(z) = c_0 + (c_1 - c_0) z + \ldots + (c_n - c_{n-1}) z^{n-1} - c_n z^n = c_0 - g(z)$$
where $ |g(z)| \le c_0$ for $|z|\le 1$ using the triangle inequality.  Equality can hold only when $|z|=1$ and all terms in $g(z)$ have the same argument, i.e. $z=1$.  Thus $(1-z)p(z)$ has no zeros in the closed unit disk except $z=1$, which is not a zero of $p(z)$.